# Most constraining variable and least constraining value for N-Queens - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, heuristics

I was trying to solve the N-Queens(Only 1 solution) problem and I succeeded but my program could only calculate up to N = 47 in a good amount of time so I tried to implement least constraining value and most constraining variable and even though it got faster, it was still slow. What can I do to be able to calculate up to N = 1000?

```
def solve(n, x, board, mid_rows, sd_squares):
    # If we are on the last row, it means we have put all the queens:
    if x >= n:
        print_board(board)
        sys.exit(0)


    for i in sd_squares:
        # If we can put a queen on the current square, do it
        if isOk(board, mid_rows[x], i, n):
            board[mid_rows[x]][i] = 1

            # Do the same thing for the next row
            solve(n, x + 1, board, mid_rows, sd_squares)

        # If we are here, it means we put the queen in the wrong square so we have to remove that queen
        board[mid_rows[x]][i] = 0
```

I can't post the whole code because it's too long but please note that `isOk(board, x, y, n)` is a function that tells if we put a queen on the x row and y column it threatens other queens or not.

mid_rows is an array that includes the most middle rows to the side rows so like let's say n = 5, then it's `[2,3,1,4,0]` or when n = 6 it's `[3,2,4,1,5,0]`.

sd_squares is a list that contains the side squares to middle squares. Like when n = 5 it's `[0,4,1,3,2]` or when n = 6 it's `[0,5,1,4,2,3]`.

Comment: Although not an answer, N-Queens can be solved *without* backtracing. In 1990 a paper showed how to solve it in *O(n^3)*, and now it can even get solved in *O(n)*. You can even obtain the position of the *k*-th queen in *O(1)*.

Comment: See here: https://fizyka.umk.pl/~milosz/AlgIILab/10.1.1.57.4685.pdf It solves 500k-Queens problems on a 25 MHz motorola processor in two hours.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I’m trying to solve the problem with backtracking.

Comment: But with a poly algorithm you can easily solve the N-Queens problem for N > 3'000'000.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem actually I’m reading a book for CSP and it says use backtracking even though there are better ways